# Get the bracketed part of Discord display name for discord bot in Python

Tags: python, discord, integer, discord.py

I'm working with discord.py and have minimal coding experience.

in my server user names are formatted like so Bruce[12345].

I'd like to be able to pull out the numbers on either ctx.author.display_name OR on user.mention and then add those numbers elsewhere.

i.e on entering command !playerid it would pull out '12345'
on entering command !playerid @johndoe[67890] it would pull out '67890'

I thought this would do it but I get an unhashable error.

```
   @bot.command()
async def playerid(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    """get playerid"""

    if user:
      playerid = user.mention
    if int in {playerid}
        int = num
      await ctx.send(f"{num}")
      await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
      selfid = (ctx.author.display_name)
      if int in {selfid}
        int = selfnum
      await ctx.send(f"{selfnum}")
      await ctx.message.delete()
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
import re

text = 'Bruce[12345]'

m = re.findall('\[[^][]*]', text)
print(m)
```

['[12345]']

Comment: you could use ```{ctx.author.name}``` and ```{user.name}```

Comment: @thesonyman101 
returns the following
 Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: You need to convert your variable to a string you can do playerid = str(playerid)